# How to set Tab width in Tab layout?

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

I'm trying to create a `tab layout` which has two `tabs`. When I run the app on small mobile the `tab layout` looks fine but when I run the same application on `Tablet` it shows like this.

It looks like this on Tablet:

[image]

I want each tab to occupy entire space without any gaps on both the ends. I have created `tab layout` like this...

```
private void drawTabLayout() {
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Imprint") );
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Legal"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(10);
    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

I have searched many sites but couldn't find the right **answer**.

Comment: from what I know either you can share equally or squeeze . Otherwise you will have to provide custom layout. Try overriding onMeasure, setting customView (your tab view)

Comment: Add your tabs width to fillParent in xml file

Comment: <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

Comment: Thank you soo much :) it worked fine @codebased

Comment: no worries I've had this problem with tablet months ago...

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Add this code in your `tab_layout.xml`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Hope it will works for you...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tab layout where each tab has a custom View and add that tab in the tablayout with whatever size of your choice

```
View customView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_text, null); 

addTab(newTab().setCustomView(customView))
```

Comment: It does not affect tab layout item, it just change view in viewpager